# Balanced Brackets using Array Stack in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, stack

I'm trying to make a program in C# to decide weather Brackets are balanced or not..
After some work i made it using Array Stack and it's working but i have 2 problems:

> 1) if i entered brackets like this way `"()[]{}(())"` it shall work
>   i.e ("I must start with only `( [ {")` but if i started the string
>   with `("})]")` it will always says unbalanced even if it was... so I'm
>   asking if someone could give me a hint for solution.
>
> 2) Is there a better way for Pop method cause the else condition is
>   just annoying me and if i removed it, it will no longer work

**Program.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Balanced_Brackets
{
    class Program
    {
        public static bool IsBalanced(string brackets)
        {
            bool balanced = false;
            MyStack s = new MyStack();
            foreach (var item in brackets)
            {
                if (item == '(' || item == '[' || item == '{')
                    s.Push(item);
                else if (item == ')' || item == ']' || item == '}')
                {
                    var poped = s.Pop();
                    if (poped == '(' && item == ')')
                         balanced = true;
                    else if (poped == '[' && item == ']')
                         balanced = true;
                    else if (poped == '{' && item == '}')
                         balanced = true;
                    else
                        return balanced = false;
                }
            }
            if (balanced == true)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string Brackets = Console.ReadLine();
            IsBalanced(Brackets);
            if (IsBalanced(Brackets))
                Console.Write("Balanced");
            else
                Console.Write("Un-Balanced");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
    class MyStack
    {
        char[] exp = new char[5];
        public int top = -1;
        public bool IsEmpty()
        {
            return (top == -1);
        }
        public bool IsFull()
        {
            return (top == exp.Length - 1);
        }
        public void Push(char a)
        {
            if (!IsFull())
                exp[++top] = a;
        }
        public char Pop()
        {
            if (!IsEmpty())
                return exp[top--];
            else
                return ' ';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If the string starts with `}` then it's properly saying it's unbalanced, unless you want it to return true for `}{`?

Comment: Please ask one question per post with [MCVE] specific to each problem (i.e. use regular `Stack` for paring part and separately ask about improving your `MyStack` code, also later may be more suitable for [CodeReview.se]). Note that as @Rob commented it is unclear what you consider valid inputs - instead of sample reading from console hardcode valid and invalid inputs as constants (may even use unit test's `Assert.IsTrue`)

Comment: I'm studying the implementation level of Stack so i can't use the stack built in IDE (user level).. And sorry it's my first post in the site.. but for now as @Rob said if entered text is "()" it will say balanced but for ")(" it will say un-balanced and I've no idea how to deal with this problem.

Comment: @AhmedAllam Well, my point was that `)(` *is* typically viewed as unbalanced brackets. If you want that to be viewed as balanced, then a stack is not the correct tool for the job here. Really, all you need to do is check that the number of `)` equal the number of `)`. Stacks are used for keeping track of state; in that the *order* of brackets are working. I'd say your code is currently correct to report it as being unbalanced.